# Let $a_1,a_2,...,a_n>0$ be such that $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> Let $a_1,a_2,...,a_n>0$ be such that $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$, then least value of
> $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(k^2-1)a_k+k^2+2k}{a_k^2+a_k+1}\text{ is,}$$

What I tried:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)\implies k=a_k\tag{$\because\sum_{k=1}^n a_k=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$}$$
So replacing $a_k$ with $k$,
$$\begin{aligned}\require{cancel}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(k^2-1)a_k+k^2+2k}{a_k^2+a_k+1}&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(k^2-1)k+k^2+2k}{k^2+k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^3-k+k^2+2k}{k^2+k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^3+k+k^2}{k^2+k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k\color{red}{\bcancel{(k^2+k+1)}}}{\color{red}{\bcancel{(k^2+k+1)}}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)
\end{aligned}$$
Is this a correct method to solve this problem? because something feels off with this as the question asks for the least value but I get a direct result.
*Please provide a correct method to solve if this is wrong*

Comment: You can't conclude that $a_k = k$ for all $k = 1,2,\ldots,n$. For instance, we could have $a_1 = 2$, $a_2 = 1$, and $a_k = k$ for all $k = 3,4,\ldots,n$. Or $a_1 = \cdots = a_{n-1} = 1$ and $a_n = n(n+1)/2-(n-1)$. There are obviously several other possibilities.

Comment: Your implication $a_k=k$ is not correct

Comment: What should the conclusion be? I do not seem to see the last part of the statement. Or is it an open question?

Answer (score 2):

Tips:
$$\frac{(k^2-1)a_k+k^2+2k}{a_k^2+a_k+1}=2k-a_k+\frac{(a_k+1)(a_k-k)^2}{a_k^2+a_k+1}\ge2k-a_k$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that
$$ a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)-\frac{1}{2}(n-1)n=n. $$
The rest is correct.

Comment: I do not think this works. What if $a_{k}=n-k+1$, for example?

Comment: I feel like $n$ is fixed in this question, otherwise this will make everything trivial.

Comment: @AndréArmatowski, if $a_k=n-k+1$, then $a_{n+1}=0$ and hence $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}a_k\neq\frac12(n+1)(n+2)$.

Comment: Yes indeed. I just think that we can only assume that for a particular $n$, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, so that we can allow for permutations of the ordinary $a_{k}=k$ and also possibly allow $a_{k}\in \mathbb{Q}$ etc.